# Is there a way to convert query string into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, symfony

I have a string like this:

```
"cart[GA117110020001]=0&cart[CA117210020001]=0&cart[ZA117210020001]=0"
```

What i try to do:

```
name_of_array[index]=value
cart[GA117110020001]=0
```

Is there a way to make an associative array called *cart* with index'es between '[ ]' and value after '='. Maybe i will do this by regular expression, but im interesting if there is simpler solution.

Comment: Do you wanna do this by php?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have a query string here, use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) for **such** strings:

```
$parts = 'cart[GA117110020001]=0&cart[CA117210020001]=0&cart[ZA117210020001]=0';
$a = [];
parse_str($parts, $a);
echo'<pre>',print_r($a),'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [GA117110020001] => 0
            [CA117210020001] => 0
            [ZA117210020001] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: That's what i looking for, thanks for fast answer :)